# Simplifying the expression with metric tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

[image]I have a very long-expression with metric tensor. How to simplify it? What is the key point to simplify?

Comment: What are you trying to calculate, and why are you doing it this way?

Comment: This related to Landau-Lifshitz pseudotensor

Comment: Landau and Lifshitz write it in a simple way. Why do you want to expand it into something complicated?

Comment: How to derive that expression in the book. That is the point.